# calculus - possible u sub or trig sub

Tags: calculus

I have a test on monday. If somebody could help me understand how to solve this problem, I would be very grateful.

$$ \int \frac{\sqrt{(9-x^2)}}{ x^4} dx, x<3 $$

the answer is supposed to be

$$- \frac{(9- x^2 )^{\frac 32}}{27x^3} + C $$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE!  If you could give us some insight into what you have tried, we may be able to help you better.

Comment: $possible$ $u$ $sub$ $or$ $trig$ $sub$. What did you try ?

Comment: i tried doing trig sub and it was working for a while, but i could see it wasn't giving me that final answer i needed to get. I figured it might have something to do with u sub because it takes that 9-x*2 and puts it back in in the final answer and the exponent around it goes from 1/2 to 3/2, making me think that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=3 \sin{t} \implies dx = 3 \cos{t} \, dt$.  Then the integral is

$$\frac{3^2}{3^4} \int \frac{\cos^2{t}}{\sin^4{t}} dt = \frac19 \int \csc^2{t}\, \cot^2{t} \, dt$$

Integrate by parts...

$$\frac19 \int \csc^2{t}\, \cot^2{t} \, dt = -\frac19 \cot^3{t} + \frac19 2 \int \cot{t}\, (-\cot{t} \csc^2{t}) \,dt $$

Therefore

$$\frac{3}{9} \int \csc^2{t}\, \cot^2{t} \, dt = -\frac19\cot^3{t}$$

or

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x^4} dx = \frac19 \int \csc^2{t}\, \cot^2{t} \, dt = -\frac1{27} \frac{\cos^3{t}}{\sin^3{t}} +C = -\frac1{27} \frac{(\sqrt{1-x^2/9})^3}{x^3/27}+C$$

The result follows.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Put $x = 3\sin \theta$.  Note that this means that $\cos \theta = (9 - x^2)^{1/2}$.

You will end up with the result $$\int \frac {\cot^2\theta\csc^2\theta}{27}\,d\theta = -\frac 1{27}\int\ \cot^2\theta(\cot\theta)'\,d\theta = -\frac 1{27}\cot^3\theta$$

Now, knowing $\cot\theta = \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}$, you'll obtain your desired result when you back substitute.

Comment: clean and simple. elegant.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note

$\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=& \displaystyle\int \dfrac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x^4} dx\\ 
&=& -\dfrac{1}{18} \displaystyle\int -\dfrac{18}{x^3} \times \sqrt{\frac{9}{x^2}-1} dx 
\end{eqnarray*}$

Then, try a sub of $u=\dfrac{9}{x^2}$.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you did in the second part. Can you please explain it more fully?

Comment: Notice that $1= -\dfrac{1}{18} \times -18$ and $\sqrt{9-x^2} = x\sqrt{\frac{9}{x^2} - 1}$. To see why I've written it as above, compute $du$ in terms of $x$ and $dx$ for the given substitution.

Comment: Oh yes, I see now. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @user137210 I made a slight arithmetic slip with using "27". I've now changed it to 18.